# How to extract the parent element using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to automate the app basic tests with Cypress. Everything until now went smooth (even CSRF token extraction). Though I hit a wall when selecting an element.

I have a situation where the same name element returns multiple results. In this case, the html below returns 7 instances. I need to pick one, how do I do that?

`<div class="EventAddButton__hover___11l17" style="opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-55px);">Add an entry</div>`

The Cypress script that I'm trying to run is:

```
it ('Create an event', function() {
    cy.get('.EventAddButton__hover___11l17').click()
  })
```

The Cypress suggests to pass the switch `multiple:true` but I need the one click.

Maybe going down the path selecting a parent?

[image]

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: and how that would look like @PanosK ?

Comment: Do these elements have a parent element that makes them unique in anyway? I am asking if they are contained in a parent element that has it own unique ID or class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please try this:**

```
cy
 .get('.EventAddButton__hover___11l17')
 .eq(0) // To click on the first element and then so on 
 .click()
```

Note: Refer to [this](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Syntax) doc pls

Comment: I up-voted this answer also. If you have access to the code perhaps you add some id that makes them unique.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an parent element for these element that makes them unique. you could

```
it ('Create an event', function() {
    cy.get('PARENT ELEMENT SELECTOR').get('.EventAddButton__hover___11l17').click()
  })
```

or

```
it ('Create an event', function() {
        cy.get('PARENT ELEMENT SELECTOR').find('.EventAddButton__hover___11l17').click()
      })
```

or if you know the index of the element you want to click

```
 it ('Create an event', function() {
        cy.eq(0).get('.EventAddButton__hover___11l17').click()
      })
```

** If you are going to do it by index select the answer by T GURUNG,..'

Comment: This is the more correct answer.  Selecting by index is very brittle.  If the number or order of elements changes your test will break.

Comment: I appreciate the vote of confidence, at the end of the day if I had access to the code I would change it to make it unique in some way. I would question those classes looking like that also, but sometimes you are testing code you can't change..

Comment: Agreed, if at all possible you should be adding a data-* attribute, but sometimes you have to resort to classes and structure.

Comment: Thank you guys for the input. That is really helpful! @Brendan